# "Would" Vs "Will"

Tags: word-usage

> ***Would*** you be my 'x'?

or

> ***Will*** you be my 'x'?

Are these both correct?

Comment: Consider x=friend. Both are correct, the former is more polite and tentative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both correct.

The subjunctive is more polite. You can find discussions of why by looking up "mitigated speech." I haven't found any explanation which I thought was convincing, so will not reproduce any here.

I *will* note that this follows the same pattern as German, where "subjunctive=polite" is much stronger.  Further, reading Feynman's description of learning to speak Japanese convinces me that a similar phenomenon exists there.

@kiamlaluno adds that this is true in Italian as well.

Comment: It is also true in Italian, where it is true not just compared with the Future Tense (yes, Italian does have a Future Tense), but also with the Present Tense (i.e. _MI sposerai?_ and _Mi sposi?_).

Comment: The subjunctive mood is not revealed here.