# Why is "would" used in this sentence, not "will?"

Tags: usage, modal-verbs, will-would

This question is about why my friend Jane used *would be* in her response to a particular language question. Here's the question:

> Context:
> Lady Catelyn's husband was murdered by Joffrey who belongs to the >Lannisters and lives in King's Landing.

> > RENLY: My lady, I swear to you I will see the Lannisters answer for your husband's murder. When I take King's Landing, I'll bring you Joffrey's head.
>
> > CATELYN: It will be enough to know that justice **was** done, my lord.

> Why use "was?" The event hasn't happened.

Here is Jane's response:

> 'Either "is" or "was" **would be** possible in that context. The idea of "was" **would be**:
>
> - "[looking back from the future] it will be enough to know that justice was done."
>
> That is, justice will have been done already by the time we look back on it.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would vs will degree of certainty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110752/would-vs-will-degree-of-certainty)

Comment: No, the thread seems different. That is not just what I'm asking. Could you help me undestand the use of "would" in the sentence above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127620/would-vs-will

Comment: Or this? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/334324/will-vs-would

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Will' vs. 'would'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158316/will-vs-would)

Comment: Who is Jane? Where did she say this? Is your question about Jane's use of "would be", or about Catelyn's use of "was"?

Comment: I would like to understand Jane's use of "would be" when she answers the question. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, Jane's remarks are not about the Lannisters and possible justice, but about the structure of an English sentence, and she is discussing it in the context of the present-day English language. She could have replaced **would be** with **is** in both places - using simple present for her remarks. Using **will be** is incorrect here because it is simple future tense. It would mean Jane says that the word choice might not be correct now, but will be correct in some future version of the English language.

Comment: I'm still confused. "Would be" is a past form of "will". Why is the asnwer made in the past? Does the "would" have other uses in this case? Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: *Will be* is future tense, not present tense. That is why Jane didn't use it here. I suppose one could argue that the "past" of the future includes the present, but in any case *would be* is sometimes used to mean *is*. It is often regarded as less blunt, or more polite, or more formal. Of course *would be* has many other uses as well.

Comment: So it's a more hypothetical way of says that it **is**, isn't it? Is there something that omits in the use of "would be" here? An implied "if"?

Comment: Sometimes there is an implied "if"; it might be "if I am correct". But consider the short dialog: Student: "The answer is 42". Maths teacher: "That would be right".

Comment: Why does Maths teacher use "would be" instead of "is?" I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Sometimes as a bit of a joke. My point is that here they mean exactly the same thing - the teacher is not at all uncertain.